# ManagementObjectSearcher and ManagementEventWatcher calls are canceled by Windows 11 with (0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))

Tags: c#, windows-11

As in the title - query in WPF .NET 5.0 app is canceled with message "Call was canceled by the message filter. (0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))"

It worked fine on Windows 10.
There are two instances which cause this issue

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\SecurityCenter2", "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
ManagementObjectCollection instances = searcher.Get();
```

In code above it throws this exception on "Get()" instruction.

```
var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
watcher.Query = new EventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 OR EventType = 3");
watcher.Start();
```

In code above it throws this exception on "Start()" instruction.

I have no idea why it occurs as it never happened on Windows 10.
The worse thing is that after a few restarts of the computer the application started normally. From what I know this problem never occurred on any station with Windows 10.